# ListView.SelectedItems does not change when clicking a TextBox in the ItemTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have a ListView bound with an ObservableCollection. The Itemtemplate of the ListView is the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="ListViewClicked" PreviewKeyDown="NameBox_KeyDown">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="./Resources/DeleteIcon.png"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This way I give the user the choice to either change the name of the element, or delete it from the list. I handle this two operations in code behind through the two event handlers attached to the ListView.

The problem is that when I click on the TextBox, the SelectedItems property of the ListView doesn't change and it points the last selected item. When I click on the image or on the free space around the selection change.

Now I have two questions:

1. Is there an easy way to fix this behavior?
2. Is it possible to get a reference to the collection item whose property is exposed by the TextBox?

Comment: do you need multiple select or single select is enough?

Comment: I am working with single.

Comment: Regarding second question. Where do you want access this list item? In `DataTemplate` or in code?

Comment: In code. I am testing your code, but I am having some problems when I click the first time (it always selects the first item no matter where i click), and I am trying to understand why

Comment: force `SelectionMode="Single"` on `ListView`. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with this problem is to set `Trigger` to set `IsSelected` when keyboard focus is within `ListViewItem`

```xml
<ListView ... SelectionMode="Single">
    <!-- .... -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin" Value="True">                        
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListView>
```

Comment: if you want to get `SelectedItem` in code behind then just cast it to the type of item in the collection.

Comment: Oh yes, I was just wondering if it is possible to get a reference directly from the TextBlock instead of calling SelectedItems.

Comment: I ask this question because I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326583/how-to-get-clicked-item-in-listview) about an ItemClick event with an ItemClickedEventArgs containing the reference, and I was hoping to find something similar.

Comment: `SelectedItem(s)` and items in `SelectionChangedEventArgs` will be of collection item type. If you have UI container like `ListViewItem`, or any of its children, then you can access item behind via `DataContext`