# Calling a method when a listview item is focused C#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, listview

I am making a small C# application where the user enters information. the information is stored in an object and the object is in turn stored in a list. The information is displayed to the user in a listview.

I want to make it so that when the user clicks on an item in the listview the index of that item is passed to the list which finds the object with the same index and gets its information. The information is then shown in the same textboxes that the user enters his or hers information in.

My problem is that i do not now what method to call when the user selects a row in the listview.

This is what i have:

```
        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
        {
            index = listView1.FocusedItem.Index;
            textBox1.Text = manager.FocusedContact(index).FirstName;
            textBox2.Text = manager.FocusedContact(index).LastName;
            textBox3.Text = manager.FocusedContact(index).Street;
            textBox4.Text = manager.FocusedContact(index).City;
            textBox5.Text = manager.FocusedContact(index).ZipCode;
        }
    }
```

i tried:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 textbox1.Text = "hi";
}
```

so i know that `private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged` is the wrong method, or is there some option for the listview that i forgot to toggle on or off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get clicked item in ListView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13326583/how-to-get-clicked-item-in-listview)

Comment: It is the right event. But it is also called when an item is unselected!! therefore the focused item may not even be selected!! Check for selectetedItems.Count and use .selectetedItems[0].!

Comment: What do you mean? I am clearly already checking for selectedItems.Count. How should i use selectedItems[0]? Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to retrieve the selected index like this:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var index = listView1.SelectedIndex;
}
```

If the event is not firing at all, check that the event handler is registered correctly in the form's Designer.cs file. In your case, it should look like this:

```
this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
```

Comment: This is what i am already doing? If you read my question i even tried: `private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  textbox1.Text = "hi";
}`To see if the event is even firing at all, which it didnt. Using this my textbox is still empty.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear from your question that the issue was the event not firing - it sounded like your main issue was that you couldn't obtain the index of the selected item.If the event isn't firing, can you check if the eventhandler is registered in your form designed.cs file. You should have: this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);

Comment: Oh i am sorry about that. Anyway, the event was not registered in the form designed.cs file. I added what you wrote and now it works! Please edit your answer so i can accept :)

Comment: No problem, glad it's helped you out - I've updated my answer, thanks